# facebook in android app

Tags: android

I want to implement a code where we click on a button and this open a facebook dialog for like functionality for my registered app. How it will be implemented?

Answer (score 2):

With the [Official Facebook for Android SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information on https://developers.facebook.com/android/

You can download Facebook SDK from this webpage and find many examples.

This link could be also helpful: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/share-using-object-api/